# Sub-additivity of the càdlàg continuity modulus

Tags: real-analysis, skorohod-space

Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and define 
$$\varpi'_f(\delta) = \inf_{\{t_i\}} \max_{i=1,\dots,n} \sup_{t,s \in [t_{i-1},t_{i})}|f(t)-f(s)|$$
where the infimum is taken over all partitions $0=t_0<t_1 < \cdots <t_n =1$ with 
$\min_{i=1,\dots,n}(t_i - t_{i-1})> \delta$.

I was trying to prove something like $$\varpi'_{f+g}(\delta) \leq \varpi'_f(\delta) + \varpi'_g(\delta)$$
but I wasn't be able to do it because of the infimus

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I suppose it's $|f(t)-f(t_{i-1})|$ in the definition of $\bar{\omega}_f'$? (Otherwise, the "$\sup_{t \in [t_{i-1},t_i)}$" doesn't make sense.)

Comment: I'm sorry it was $\sup_{t,s \in [t_{i-1},t_i)}|f(t)-f(s)|$

Comment: I think it should say "where the infimum is taken over all positive integers $n$ and all partitions $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=1$ such that $\min_{i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}}(t_i-t_{i-1})>\delta$."

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take:

\begin{align}
&f(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $0 \leq x < 0.5$} \\
1  & \mbox{ if $0.5 \leq x \leq 1$} 
\end{array}
\right.\\
&g(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $0 \leq x < 0.6$} \\
1  & \mbox{ if $0.6 \leq x \leq 1$} 
\end{array}
\right.\\
\end{align}

Then $\varpi_f'(0.3) = \varpi_g'(0.3) = 0$ but $\varpi_{f+g}'(0.3)=1$.